# Usage of "compensate" with "work"?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

Assuming that I'm going to leave early today.
And I would like to say that *"I will work at tonight to compensate for the lost time"*.

Is it correct to say like that?
Should I use *"make up"* in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are equivalent in meaning in this case. The primary difference is that "make up" is more conversational while "compensate" is more formal.

If you're telling someone face to face, it would probably seem more natural to say "make up." If you're sending an email, either would be acceptable depending on the tone of the rest of the email. "Compensate" may even be too formal for this case.

---

As for the general difference between these expressions, "make up for" is usually used conversationally with reference to a past action (or inaction as it may be) or the presence or absence of something.

For example:

> I will work tonight to make up for leaving early today.

(Action performed in the past)

> I will work tonight to make up for my early departure.

(Presence of a noun)

"Compensate" is usually associated with more technical speech. "Compensate" would always be used instead of "make up" when discussing engineering, for example.

> In order to compensate for the effect of air resistance, the rocket has been designed as aerodynamically as possible.

(Technical jargon)

"*Over*-compensate," however, is common in everyday speech, since "Over make up" does not exist. "Overcompensate" can also be used in a technical context as well.

---

**P.S.** Say either "I will work *tonight*..." or "I will work *at night*..."

Comment: I'm sending it via an instant messaging system. May I just say _"I will work tonight to compensate"_? (because I think that everyone would understand _"for the lost time"_ in this case). Thanks for your P.S.

Comment: @quanta Even though people will be able to figure out what you mean, it is uncommon for either phrase to be used without stating a reason. I'm not sure as to why this is.

Comment: @quanta: Yes you can say that "I need to step out ( or leave ) early today and will work late in the evening (or in the night) to compensate for that". I have seen this precise thing very recently in my office. Ultimately, what matters is that you convey your message clearly that you are leaving earlier than usual, but you will make up for that.

Comment: @V_Singh This is true. I hadn't though annoy that instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can say that `I need to step out ( or leave ) early today and will work late in the evening (or in the night) to compensate for that`. You can even use `make up`. I have seen this precise thing (with `make up` usage) very recently in my office. Ultimately, what matters is that you convey your message clearly that you are leaving earlier than usual, but there will not be any loss of productivity.